# Populating a View Model with a foreach loop when one field could be null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, foreach

I have some old tables from an old database which I am trying to use to populate a View Model. The controller action looks for records in one old table where the email matches the current users email and then populates the View Model based on a list derived from those matches.  This is my controller action:

```
public PartialViewResult OldCourses()
    {
        var email = User.Identity.GetEmail();

        var reglist = nb.old_register
            .Where(i => i.email == email).ToList();

        if (reglist != null)
        {
            var viewModel = new OldCourseViewModel();

            foreach (var reg in reglist)
            {
                viewModel.StudentID = reg.studentid;
                viewModel.CourseTitle = nb.old_courses.FirstOrDefault(j => j.courseid == nb.old_Cohorts.FirstOrDefault(h => h.cohortname == reg.cohort).modulename).coursetitle;
                viewModel.Cohort = reg.cohort;
                viewModel.Progpct = nb.student_progress.FirstOrDefault(k => k.studentid == reg.studentid).percentage;
            };


            return PartialView("OldCourses", viewModel);
        }
```

It is possible for viewModel.Progpct to return null as there may not be an entry in the student_progress table for each record in reglist.  This means I get an error, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The View Model is as follows:

```
public class OldCourseViewModel
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string CourseTitle { get; set; }
    public string Cohort { get; set; }
    public decimal? Progpct { get; set; }
    public string icon_class { get; set; }
    public string icon_colour_class { get; set; }
    public string titleabbrev { get; set; }

}
```

The field 'percentage' from the old table is as follows:

```
public Nullable<decimal> percentage { get; set; }
```

None of the old tables have foreign key relationships and I can't change any of those tables in any way.

I appreciate that the foreach loop can't handle the null, even though the field is nullable in the View Model.

My first question is what is the best way to handle this situation so that this field can be returned null when it is null?

My second question is, if there are multiple records in the reglist, how can I make the foreach loop cycle through each record in the reglist and generate a new record in the View Model for each of those in the reglist?

Edit - On Stephen's suggestion, I did the following:

```
var pctcheck = nb.student_progress.FirstOrDefault(k => k.studentid == reg.studentid);

                if (pctcheck != null)
                {
                    viewModel.Progpct = pctcheck.percentage;
                }
```

This answers my first question correctly.  Stephen also answered my second question correctly in the comments.

The accepted answer is the best way of completing my first question, rather than the above I used:

```
viewModel.Progpct = nb.student_progress.FirstOrDefault(k => k.studentid == reg.studentid)?.percentage;
```

Which uses the ?. operator to do the same job as the if null check.

Comment: Assign the result of `FirstOrDefault()` to a variable and test if its null before setting the value of the property

Comment: Thanks, I had considered that, I just assumed there might be a better method.  I had been trying to use the ?? operator and the likes to no avail.  Presumably, if you say so, that's the best method.

Comment: Hello, I believe I tried your suggestion correctly but I receive the same error.  Please see my edit for what I attempted.

Comment: No, You have to remove the `.percentage` (you cannot access a property of `null` - then its  `if (pctcheck != null) { viewModel.Progpct = pctcheck.percentage; };`

Comment: Are you sure it's not the `nb.student_progress` property that's null?

Comment: That makes sense, thanks Stephen.  I'll re-edit my post.

Comment: For the 2nd, your model needs to be `List<OldCourseViewModel>` and inside the loop, you initialize a new `OldCourseViewModel`, set its properties and add it to the collection

Comment: Perfect, that works also, I'll add it to my question.  If you create a question I'll mark it as an answer, although as you always respond in the comments  perhaps you aren't bothered.  You're a bit like Batman Stephen, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, even if you fixed it, you may use, in new versions of c#, the  `?.` operator

```
viewModel.Progpct = nb.student_progress.FirstOrDefault(k => k.studentid == reg.studentid)?.percentage;
```

in older versions, you may use

```
viewModel.Progpct = nb.student_progress.Where(k => k.studentid == reg.studentid).Select(m => (decimal?)m.percentage).FirstOrDefault();
```

for the second question, you could simplify with something like that.

Your model will be an `IEnumerable<OldCourseViewModel>`

```
var email = User.Identity.GetEmail();

var model = nb.old_register.Where(i => i.email == email)
     .Select(reg => new OldCourseViewModel {

           StudentID = reg.studentid,
           CourseTitle = nb.old_courses.FirstOrDefault(j => j.courseid == nb.old_Cohorts.FirstOrDefault(h => h.cohortname == reg.cohort)?.modulename)?.coursetitle;
           Cohort = reg.cohort,
           Progpct = nb.student_progress.FirstOrDefault(k => k.studentid == reg.studentid)?.percentage
       });

return PartialView("OldCourses", model);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can't seem to use the ?. operator in the way you have denoted.  I get the error "an expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator".  I'm using version 6 of c# according to the webconfig.  Presumably this isn't a new enough version?

Comment: Ah, from what I've read it is because ?. does not remain c# code, Linq translates it directly to SQL and thus doesn't understand it.  I can use the ?. operator in the original query format of my question but it doesn't appear I can use it in the more efficient format you suggested in your answer.  Thanks for your answer either way, it was informative.

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer as I don't think Stephen really cares and your ?. operator used in my original query is the best solution to my first question.